# CSSセレクタの中にある「>」

Tags: css, jquery

jQueryのCSSセレクタの中にある「>」の存在理由がわかりません。

元のhtml

```
<div id="button1">
<button>aaa-btn<span class="big">
       <span>aaa</span></span></button>
```

css

```
何かしら適当な色や形状
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
   $("#button1 .big).on("mouseover",function(){
   $(this).find(">span").stop(true).animate({   //////
```

という風に後はいろいろと続くのですが、この (">span") の中の「>」の意味がわかりません。これは何を意味するのでしょうか？無くても普通に動いているようですが。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CSSセレクタの1つで **直下の子要素のみ** を指定したい場合に用います。
`>`を付けないと、孫要素に`span`があった場合にも候補になります。

cf. [意外と知らない!?CSSセレクタ20個のおさらい｜Webpark](http://weboook.blog22.fc2.com/blog-entry-268.html)